# Regex do not contain

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

Been asked a few times on SO but I can't get mine to work.
Regex in C#
I want to search for text like this template

```
xxx yyy(zzz)
```

where x,y,z can be a-z, A-Z, 0-9.

It

- should not contain **scope** in *xxx* part
- contain only **done** in *zzz* part
- contain only **status** in *yyy* part

Text to match against

```
testscope status(done)
devscope status(wait)
retest status(done), dev1scope status(wait)
```

As highlighted, I want to find only **retest status(done)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
\b(?<!scope)[ \t]+status\(done\).*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[^(scope)]+([ ]status[(]done[)])

**[^(scope)]+** - Any char sequence except 'scope';

**([ ]status[(]done[)])** - string ' status(done)'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

```
 #  @"\b(?!\w*scope)[^\W_]+[ \t]status\(done\)"

 \b                     # Word boundry so s'cope' is not matched
 (?! \w* scope )        # Not 'scope' ahead
 [^\W_]+                # Words, not underscore
 [ \t]                  # Single tab or space
 status\(done\)         # 'status(done)'
```